# BigInteger to string in reasonable time

Tags: java, string, performance, biginteger

I am writing a program where time is important, and I just realized through a lot of debugging prints that my big holdup (80% of computing time) is converting a very large BigInteger (50K digits) into a string.
Is this behavior to be expected or how can I change something to make it run faster?

Comment: Do you actually do calculations with that BigInteger?

Comment: an exponent, a division, and a multiplication

Comment: And do you need the result to be a String?

Comment: I need to put it into a file.

Comment: Can you dump it as binary, avoiding the conversion to decimal? I assume you don't need to read the 50K digit number yourself?

Comment: no, but a grading program does.

Comment: You have a grading program that needs 50,000 digits of precision?

Comment: yes, I do. The answer my program gets, which I have checked for correctness, is over 50K digits long. However, my program runs in 1.5s and the limit is 1s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting numbers to strings is an expensive operation even if you use `long` and `double`.

Normally, the only thing more expensive is the IO you perform when writing the text for a file or the console.

It is worth noting that the built in converter a number to text is an O(N^2) operation where N is the number of digits.  As such it is not surprising that 50K digit numbers take a very long time to convert to a decimal String.

---

Based on tmyklebu's suggestion I have written this.  It is slower for numbers with less than 500 digits, but is much faster in the range of 50,000 digits.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(11).pow(48100);
    System.out.println(bi.toString());
    System.out.println(toString(bi));
    System.out.println("bi.length=" + bi.toString().length() + ", toString(bi).length=" + toString(bi).length());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        String s = bi.toString();
        long mid = System.nanoTime();
        String s2 = toString(bi);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("time1 %.3f ms, time2 %.3f ms%n", (mid - start) / 1e6, (end - mid) / 1e6);
        if (!s.equals(s2))
            throw new AssertionError();
    }
}

public static String toString(BigInteger bi) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 16;
    while (bi.compareTo(powerOfTen(i)) > 0)
        i *= 2;
    toString(bi, sb, i);
    int start = 0;
    while (sb.charAt(start) == '0')
        start++;
    return sb.substring(start);
}

private static void toString(BigInteger bi, StringBuilder sb, int digits) {
    if (digits < 18) {
        int start = sb.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++)
            sb.append('0');
        long l = bi.longValue();
        for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0; i--, l /= 10)
            sb.setCharAt(start + i, (char) ('0' + l % 10));
    } else {
        int digits2 = digits / 2;
        BigInteger[] parts = bi.divideAndRemainder(powerOfTen(digits2));
        toString(parts[0], sb, digits - digits2);
        toString(parts[1], sb, digits2);
    }
}

private static final Map<Integer, BigInteger> powersOfTen = new HashMap<Integer, BigInteger>();

private static BigInteger powerOfTen(int digits2) {
    BigInteger tens = powersOfTen.get(digits2);
    if (tens == null)
        powersOfTen.put(digits2, tens = BigInteger.TEN.pow(digits2));
    return tens;
}
```

prints

```
973096948397248203274473625697464617461138859359846077811290536......
973096948397248203274473625697464617461138859359846077811290536......
bi.length=50091, toString(bi).length=50091
time1 525.892 ms, time2 67.260 ms
time1 458.559 ms, time2 98.178 ms
time1 441.275 ms, time2 92.902 ms
time1 399.339 ms, time2 98.448 ms
time1 518.761 ms, time2 97.804 ms
time1 396.884 ms, time2 65.651 ms
time1 363.945 ms, time2 98.827 ms
```

Comment: It is a homework assignment whose result needs to be accurate. So I should probably find a better algorithm?

Comment: I assume then that the homework need a particular format. If it has to be decimal, there isn't a simple solution to make it faster. Don't forget the built in code has been developed by senior developers over many years. I would assume most of the simple solutions to make things faster have been considered.

Comment: I mean some shortcut that does not require me to to use BigInteger. Although, Parvin's answer on this question points out that toString() is not optimized for any specific radix.

Comment: While that is true, I have written a version which is optimised for 10^18 radix and it is less than 1% faster.

Comment: Fundamentally, conversion to any radix other than a power of 2 is an O(N^2) operation as you need to perform repeated division for each digits and that is O(N) as the division itself is longer.  The only way to reduce the cost is to use a library which use base 10 (or 100, 1000 etc) but this will slow down your other operations.

Comment: As this is a CPU inensive process you could convert each number in a different thread, this could speed up you time by the number of CPUs you have.

Comment: I will just have to optimize it in some other way.

Comment: That is where using multiple threads could help if you have multiple numbers to convert.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: No, you don't need quadratic time to do radix conversion.  O(n polylog(n)) time is quite enough.  Divide the thing you're trying to radix-convert into an upper half and a lower half in the source radix.  Convert both halves.  Multiply (in the target radix) the upper half by the right amount (since it is the upper half).  Add the results (in the target radix).  I think GMP has something similar that's less horrible in practice.

Comment: My linear toString gave almost exactly the same times as the builtin function (within experiemental erro shall we say) I will try this and see if it is any faster.

Comment: That would be "experimental error"

Comment: @tmyklebu It appears we are both not quite right.  As you suggest this approach is much faster for very large numbers, and it doesn't appear that the built in conversion uses this, but I suspect it should.

Comment: @Jake223 It appears that tmyklebu's suggest is about 4x faster than the built in method.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:  Nice bit of code.  You could speed it up more if you had a base-10 *multiply* that didn't suck --- instead of splitting the argument in base 10 using a (relatively slow) divide-and-mod, you split the argument in base 2 and you do a base 10 multiply and add when combining the results.

Comment: @tmyklebu Sounds interesting but I don't multiply by 10 anywhere only `% 10` and `/ 10` I do a power of ten but this is 10^(2^n),so not that many and these are cached so have no impact after being called the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post about [Performance of BigInteger.toString(radix)](http://royontechnology.blogspot.com/2010/10/performance-of-bigintegertostringradix.html). It could give you an idea.

Comment: That's for hexadecimal, not decimal.